# Page Not Found custom routes Nuxt i18n v8

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt-i18n

Hi i have and error with "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-rc.4",

When i define de custom routes this way the site throws a 404. with all the renamed routes but not with the folder path:

FAILS: https://www.example.com/en/group/subsidiaries (false url)
WORKS: https://www.example.com/en/grupo/offices (false url)

I add my configuration with the custom route example:

```
    i18n: {
        //strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        locales: [
            {
                code: 'de',
                iso: 'de-DE',
                file: 'de-DE.js'
            },
            {
                code: 'en',
                iso: 'en-GB',
                file: 'en-GB.js'
            },
            {
                code: 'us',
                iso: 'en-US',
                file: 'en-US.js'
            },
            {
                code: 'fr',
                iso: 'fr-FR',
                file: 'fr-FR.js'
            },
            {
                code: 'it',
                iso: 'it-IT',
                file: 'it-IT.js'
            },
        ],
        lazy: true,
        langDir: 'langs',
        legacy: false,
        experimental: {jsTsFormatResource: true},
        //////Up here is working. Down here is failing ////////
        customRoutes: 'config',
        pages: {
            'grupo/offices': {
                      en: '/group/subsidiaries',
                      us: '/group/subsidiaries',
                  de: '/gruppe/tochtergesellschaften',
                      fr: '/groupe/filiales',
                      it: '/gr
uppo/sussidiarie',
            },
        },

    },
```

I try to internazionalize routes with nuxt i18n v8 and Nuxt 3